# Install SQL Server Express r2 2008 using a configuration file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I need to deploy my application with SQL Server Express. There is a way of installing sql express using a configuration file so that when deploying my application it appears as if I am only installing one thing and make it easier for the user installing the software. Anyways here are the steps:

### Step 1)

Create the configuration file:
[image]

### Step 2)

Place the Setup.exe ([SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXP08V2/enus/default.aspx))  file next to the configuration file. I place both files at the root of my c drive for simplicity

### Step 3)

Execute the setup.exe passing the parameters:
[image]

---

I been getting a lot of errors. Can someone show me how can I have a configuration file in order to install sql server express edition with the administrator as the main user.I don't want the user installing the application to have to go throughout that trouble. I found a [nice link that teaches you how to create a configuration file in here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx) but I still am not able to do it. I am using windows xp 32 bit. I managed to installed it on the virtual machine manually. I will like to be able to install sql server express from the command line or with a configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot install SQL Express without Administrator rights on the machine and it's not something you can set in the config file or on the command line. If being able to install without Administrator rights is a requirement, you may want to investigate using [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).

See the following MSDN topics for more information:

- [Using SQL Server Compact 3.5 (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983321.aspx)
- [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx)
- [SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734673.aspx)
- [Local Data Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx)
- [Choosing Between SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition and SQL Server 2005 Express Edition](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc) -- A little dated now, but much of it still applies.

Answer (score 0):

### The configuration file

```
[SQLServer2008]
INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"
ACTION="Install"
FEATURES=SQLENGINE
HELP="False"
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
X86="False"
ERRORREPORTING="False"
SQMREPORTING="False"
INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
ENABLERANU="True"
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"
SECURITYMODE="SQL"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"
SAPWD="123456"
TCPENABLED="0"
NPENABLED="0"
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
```

---

The command line to install from package:

```
f:\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe /QS /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms  /ConfigurationFile="f:\ConfigurationFile.ini"
```

---

Another command to install:

```
setup.exe /QS /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms  /ConfigurationFile="f:\ConfigurationFile.ini"
```